# How do I make my Picasa album public?

Tags: picasa-web-albums

I wish to make it public so I can have it embedded in my website. But I swear I cannot find how to change it from private to public.

I'm in no way computer literate, but I just cannot find it!

Comment: Yah I would of done but I do blue have enough rep on super user to answer my own question and post images. I'll come back and change it when I do!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe this link is what you are looking for [how to change permissions in Picasa](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/39551?hl=en)

This link contains instructions on how to do it. [link](https://support.google.com/picasa/answer/113516?hl=en)

Comment: You see I'm not seeing the options they say are there, for instance, http://gyazo.com/276d08a548b662d56e3016916bd67bca and http://gyazo.com/276d08a548b662d56e3016916bd67bca Here. Also in options within picasa, http://gyazo.com/a8a68648b2ecd78da583509ca2e28061 there is no "Web Albums" tab it claims i should click.

Comment: Is yours the latest version?

Comment: Yes i think I may have found the answer though. None from above, I'll post if it worked i'll need to go and test it.